# How to compare two char* variables

Tags: java, c, algorithm

Suppose we have the following method (it is in c code):

```
const char *bitap_search(const char *text, const char *pattern)
```

My question is how can I compare text and pattern if they are `char`? This method is like a substring problem but I am confused a bit can I write in term of char such code?
`if (text[i]==pattern[i])`?
look i am interesting   at this algorithm    in java
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitap_algorithm
how implement this in java?

```
R = malloc((k+1) * sizeof *R);
```

and please help me to translate this code in java
  so we have two string text?
 like "i like computer    it is very important"
  and  patter string " computer   it is very"?
can anybody  explain me what we have instead  of char?

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are asking, could you rephrase this?

Comment: substring   problem in terms of char  or we should find if text contains almost pattern    and text  and pattern are not  string  they are char

Comment: They are not `char`, they are pointers to `char` which is what “strings” are in C (i.e. arrays of characters terminated with a NUL character).

Comment: To somewhat echo earlier statements - it is considered good manners and good form on Stack Overflow to accept an answer if one has been provided that helped you solve your problems, and to upvote answers that helped you out, even if they didn't directly solve your problem.

Comment: You should specify Java **OR** C, as string handling is very different between the two.  For example, Java has a `String` class and C doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused about the difference between `char` and `char *`.  In C there is no built-in string type.  Strings are represented as null-terminated character arrays, meaning that the last character of the string must be `\0`  So `char` is a single character, while `char *` is a pointer to an array of characters, i. e. a string.  And that means that it is perfectly fine to say `if (text[i] == pattern[i])`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what exactly you are asking, but if you mean to find `pattern` in `text`, then `strstr(text, pattern)`. Or if you mean to just compare `text` and `pattern`, then `strcmp(text, pattern)` (note that it returns `0` when `text` and `pattern` are equal).

**Edit based on discussion in comments:** If you mean to ask how to implement the indexing of individual characters in Java, then substitute (in Java) `text.charAt(i)` for the C `text[i]`. In C the chars in strings can be indexed directly like an array, in Java one needs to call the correct method in [String](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

**Edit 2**: The C code `const char *` can be replaced in Java with `String`.

In C `malloc` is used to allocate memory; in this case it allocates room in the array `R` for `m+1` elements. So, the `BIT *R` can be removed and `R = malloc((m+1) * sizeof *R);` replaced with `boolean[] R = new boolean[m + 1];`. When assigning values into the array `R` substitute `true` for `1` and `false` for `0`.

Comment: @davit-datuashvili: Umm, that Wikipedia page already contains a C implementation of this algorithm. Are you confused about some aspect of that code? If so, please edit your question with to ask about that specifically (and link to the Wikipedia page from there).

Comment: i am planning to implement in java 
how rite this?   R = malloc((k+1) * sizeof *R);
?

Comment: Please edit that into the actual question at the top; as you can see most people trying to answer you have no idea what you actually mean to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You might try these:

- Google-diff-match-patch says that it
  has [a
  java implementation of Bitap](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/).
- Also, it appears that [crosswire
  has an implementation](http://www.crosswire.org/jsword/api/org/crosswire/common/diff/Bitap.html).
- Finally, there
  seems to be a package called [String
  Search](http://johannburkard.de/software/stringsearch/), whose title is
  **High-perfor­mance pattern matching
  algo­rithms in Java**.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need `strcmp()` or `strpos()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `strncmp()`. The syntax is something like:

```
int strncmp( const char *str1, const char *str2, size_t count );
```

It is the best and more secure way of comparing strings, but of course you will need to know their length, or at least the minimum length between them.

Comment: if (pattern[0] == '\0')  it means that pattern.length==0 yes? because it is at the begining of code